# How to set a model boolean field based on conditional logic of other field values

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Template model with a 1:many FK with a Post model:

```py
class Template(model.Models):
    #foo

class Post(model.Models):
    template = models.ForeignKey(
        Template, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

I want to create an 'automatic' boolean field that flags if there is one or more posts using the template (if `True` I will lock the template for editing).

What's the best way to do this? Is it via a `@property` decorator on the `Template` model??:

```py
@property
def can_edit(self):
    if self.object.post_set.all() >= 1:
        self._can_edit = True
        return self._can_edit
    else:
        self._can_edit = False
        return self._can_edit
```

Then I would call this via `{{ template.can_edit }}` to display the flag status and `{% if template.can_edit() %}` to run conditional logic, but this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
@property
def can_edit(self):
    return self.post_set.count() == 0
```

And in your template:

```
{% if template.can_edit %}
```

Comment: Thanks, how could I print the status of can_edit in the template? Would I need to wrap it in `{%}`  or can I call it as a value with `{{`?

Comment: Is it possible to use this in a generic view to redirect based on the `can_edit` value?

Comment: Yes, in that case you would use `self.object.can_edit` for example if you are using `UpdateView`.

Comment: Thanks, what's the best way to go about doing this? I've opened a question here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57724022/how-to-redirect-in-a-generic-view