# How to redirect in a Generic View

Tags: django, django-views

I am using a generic view to render my blog post item:

```
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Post
    # etc
```

I have a model method on the `Post` model that results in a boolean `True` or `False`:

```
@property
def can_edit(self):
    return self.displays_set.count() == 0
```

If `can_edit` is `False` for the `Post` object, how can I refactor the view to redirect from my `UpdateView` to a different `DetailView`?

Comment: Look at [this](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/) to understand how the `UpdateView` works and where you'd want to redirect. The method to override depends a bit on your flow. E.g. does this happen on GET or POST? You can see the `object` of the view (your `Post`) gets fetched in the first line of `get()` and `post()`, so after that you can check your condition and redirect if necessary. If you need it for both, then override `dispatch()`.

Comment: Note that the mixin should come first, i.e. `class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `dispatch` method, and check `obj.can_edit` there. That way the object will be checked for `get` and `post` requests.

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if not obj.can_edit:
            return redirect('/readonly-view/')

        return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

With this solution, `get_object()` is called twice so there is a duplicate SQL query. However this is probably worth it to keep the code simple.

Comment: Nice solution, however, I would rather redirect in `get` and `post` separately to avoid extra database hit.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that override `dispatch` method is best solution,
but if you want to avoid extra database hit, then you need to override `get` and `post` methods

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    if not obj.can_edit:
        return redirect('/readonly-view/')

    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object = self.get_object()
    if not obj.can_edit:
        return redirect('/readonly-view/')

    form = self.get_form()
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```